# Chinese Django Admin not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set the Django Admin to display English. This is what I got in the `settings` file.

```
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('zh-tw', gettext('Traditional Chinese'))
)
```

This is from the example of the [Official docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/global_settings.py).

However, this is the traceback I'm receiving:

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

```
Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'myapp']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py" in process_request
  16.         language = translation.get_language_from_request(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py" in get_language_from_request
  124.     return _trans.get_language_from_request(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py" in get_language_from_request
  369.     supported = dict(settings.LANGUAGES)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

it seems it is expecting a 2 character string for the first element of the tuple... However in the docs it says to use `zh-tw`, I'm really at a loss...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a missing comma:

```
LANGUAGES = (
     ('zh-tw', gettext('Traditional Chinese')), # <= add a comma here
)
```